# Spring WebFlux | Static Code Analysis Tool to detect unused Mono / Flux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, static-code-analysis

Is there any static code analysis tool available that can spot at compile-time whether a returned Mono or Flux was not used / subscribed to?
E.g.

```
public Mono<Void> someReactiveMethod() { ... }

// if you forget to subscribe to the returned Mono you will have fun at runtime
someReactiveMethod(); // should raise an error
```

Comment: [Error Prone](https://github.com/google/error-prone) will detect these sorts of things with a bit of poking and tweaking.

Comment: Some IDEs are already implementing live inspections like this. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175780

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no static code checks for that yet but you may want to take a look at the [`PublisherProbe`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-test/src/main/java/reactor/test/publisher/PublisherProbe.java) class in `reactor-core`, which let's you easily test if `Publisher`/`Mono`/`Flux` was subscribed or not.